# How can I use sub directory php file request values in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have path like www.example.com/coupon/searchresult.php?txtCity=Chennai&txtArea=Annanagar. For the above sub folder's path files htaccess is not working. This is the first time i'm using htaccess. So please provide your answer. Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Please show your current .htaccess file.

Comment: what is the code of your current htacces ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/coupon/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$  searchresult.php?txtcity=$1&txtarea=$2
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/coupon/$  searchresult.php?txtcity=$1&txtarea=$2
```

pls use this one and modify as you wish it will help you sure !

Comment: The above code also not working in htaccess.I used like "RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/coupon/$  searchresult.php?txtcity=$1&txtarea=$2 [QSA,L]". Any other solution to solve this problem?